# get route in laravel overriding resource route , How to overcome this

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following route in my laravel route file:

```
Route::get('/{id}' , [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@show',
    'as' => 'getArticle'
]);
```

The problem with the above route is , its overriding the below route:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'adminController');
```

I want to keep my resource route, but how do i keep my resource ? is there a way around this ??

Comment: aren't those two different routes? how are they overriding? or did you mean /admin/{id}?

Comment: Just put Route::resource('admin', 'adminController'); BEFORE the other one. Routes are evaluated in the order that they are listed in routes.php

Comment: Is your `Route::get(...)` inside a `Route::group()` with a prefix of "admin"?

Comment: Modify your route file in the order that the one with `id` is set at the end. Look for my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your route file like this.

```
Route::resource('admin', 'adminController');

Route::get('/{id}' , [ 'uses' => 'PagesController@show', 'as' => 'getArticle' ]);
```

Route files executed in the order they are defined.

If you define `Route::get('/{id}',....` in the beginning and set your url like `http://your-site/admin`, the `admin` section will be considers as the `id` for the `Route::get('/{id}',....` route. So you need to keep it in your mind when you define your route.

Answer (score 1):

just move this route in the end of the web.php file.

```
Route::get('/{id}' , [
'uses' => 'PagesController@show',
'as' => 'getArticle'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- move `Route::get('/{id}', ...)` after `Route::resource(...)`
- or add a pattern to `Route::get()` if `id` is numeric `Route::get('/{id}', ...)->where('id', '[0-9]+');`